# Post to another's Facebook wall with Social Framework in iOS 6

Tags: facebook, ios6, social-framework

I am making an App that reads a business' Facebook feed.  The app is registered, I have an App ID, and can view all posts to their wall.  I want users of my App to be able to post a comment on the business' wall.  Is this possible with the Social Framework?  I have seen many posts that say you can no longer post to a friends wall, but this App is registered. I can post to the user of my App's wall, but I want to post to the account that is registered with the app.  Does anyone have any idea how to go about this.  Please comment if you have any questions. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?  Or can this just not be done.  Any body have any thing to say?

Comment: Douglas, you state: "I can post to the user of my App's wall,"  How do you even do that with the social framework?

Comment: @user1639164, I followed a tut by Geeky Lemon Drop.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck001hDnp-Q.  It makes a view with the social framework that lets you post to your own Facebook wall.  It basically updates your status.  Very quick to implement.  Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I misinterpreted your statement a bit.  I am looking for a method to allow my app user to post to their friends wall. Thanks tho!

Comment: @user1639164, I really think they took that option away.  I tried all sorts of things and searches and found nothing.  Best of luck.

Comment: if they have removed the ability to post on a friends wall, what is the go-to strategy for inviting friends to use your app?  There has to be a good way to do this...

Comment: @user1639164, If this is an iPhone app, I have just "liked" my apps on the iTunes Store and it posted to my wall.  I have also shared my links to all my apps as well on FB.